# Warning: ftp_put() expects parameter 3 to be a valid path, array given

Tags: php, upload

I'm trying to upload a single file to my ftp directory but unable to upload the file.   I keep getting the following error

Warning: ftp_put() expects parameter 3 to be a valid path, array given

```
<form action="" class="tsc_form_contact_light frame tbar" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">       
    <label for="name">ArtWork Name <font color='red'>(required)</font></label>   
    <input type="upload" name="artname" class="form-input" required />
    <label for="name">ArtWork Image</label>     
    <input type="file" id="uploadfile" name="uploadfile"> 
    </form>

    $path_of_storage = '/public_html/newinvoice/orderimage/';
    $newftpdir = $_SESSION['SESS_ORDER_ID'];

    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftpserver);
    ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 
    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftplogin, $ftppass);

    //ftp_mksubdirs($conn_id,$path_of_storage,$newftpdir);

            $source_file = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'];
        $destination_file = "$path_of_storage".$source_file;
        $destination = "$path_of_storage";          

            // check connection
            if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
                echo "FTP connection has failed!";
                exit; 
            } else {
                echo "Connected";
            }

            // upload the file
            $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY); 

            $name = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"];
            move_uploaded_file($source_file, "$destination/$name");

    // check upload status
    if (!$upload) { 
    echo "FTP upload has failed! $destination_file";
    } else {
    echo "Uploaded $source_file as $destination_file";
    }

    // close the FTP stream 
    ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

$_FILES contains array of all the uploaded file along with the attributes like name, type,  tmp_path etc

Use $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'] for the file path

Refer to this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) for more details

Comment: now I get error 

Warning: ftp_put(): Can't open that file: No such file or directory in

FTP upload has failed! /public_html/newinvoice/orderimage/tmp/phpvu88kM

Comment: php temporarily store uploaded file to this path
if you want to move the uploaded file to some other directory then use this function move_uploaded_file() http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: I changed tmp_name to name and now get the following

Warning: ftp_put(photoupload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  FTP upload has failed! /public_html/newinvoice/orderimage/photoupload.php

Comment: name attribute does not contains the file path..it contain the name of the field. Please refer http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: I updated my code above with what you provided and now get -----Connected
Warning: ftp_put(): Can't open that file: No such file or directory 
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/public_html/newinvoice/orderimage/photoupload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpKd0Bu7' to '/public_html/newinvoice/orderimage/photoupload.php' --- FTP upload has failed!

Comment: validate whether any files are getting uploaded or not in the default directory..is there any file/directory permission issue

Comment: I removed $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY); ------ and now it works